# Android Studio - Copy and Paste img into drawable folder does not work

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Help! I was trying to import some images (png) into the drawable folder in Android Studio. When I copied the file (cmd+c) and pasted it (cmd+v) into the folder, nothing happened！  I also tried drag and drop. Not working either.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1 in Mac El Capitan. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Very strange. Drag and drop should work fine in AS. Do you have any errors or messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If copy paste and drag drop are not working in your system, try this

- Goto workspace (where your project folder)
- Go to app folder and then drawable folder where you want images
- paste your images there
- clean your project. All images will import automatically in
  Android Studio project

Comment: this does not work. Android Studio is buggy. Classic Googlers...